# Improving my minesweeper algorithm c#

Tags: c#, loops, solver, minesweeper

I'm making a minesweeper game, and so far it's completely playable and you can finish the game. However, my solving algorithm sucks. It's pretty messy and I'm looking for a cleaner way, perhaps with loops, but I can't think of anything.

Here is what i'm currently using:

I have four global lists:

```
    List<String> flaggedButtons = new List<String>();
    List<String> minedNodes = new List<String>();
    List<String> playingField = new List<String>();
    List<String> adjacence = new List<String>();
```

and this is the method that utilizes the lists to solve the game:

Entire method: http://pastebin.com/7J2Fc8yw

most important parts:

```
            char btnLetter = Convert.ToChar(buttonName.Substring(0, buttonName.Length - 1));
            char aboveLetter = btnLetter; aboveLetter--;
            char belowLetter = aboveLetter; belowLetter++; belowLetter++;
            int upDown = Convert.ToInt32(buttonName.Substring(1));
            int leftSide = Convert.ToInt32(buttonName.Substring(1)) - 1;
            int rightSide = Convert.ToInt32(buttonName.Substring(1)) + 1;

            //Clear the list by making a new list before adding the new values as to not overlap.
            adjacence = new List<String>();

            //Put all adjacent sides in to a list
            adjacence.Add(Convert.ToString(btnLetter.ToString() + leftSide));
            adjacence.Add(Convert.ToString(btnLetter.ToString() + rightSide));
            adjacence.Add(Convert.ToString(aboveLetter.ToString() + leftSide));
            adjacence.Add(Convert.ToString(aboveLetter.ToString() + rightSide));
            adjacence.Add(Convert.ToString(belowLetter.ToString() + leftSide));
            adjacence.Add(Convert.ToString(belowLetter.ToString() + rightSide));
            adjacence.Add(Convert.ToString(aboveLetter.ToString() + upDown));
            adjacence.Add(Convert.ToString(belowLetter.ToString() + upDown));
```

Basically this is the part that I need help with. It works, but it's messy. I know I should be using loops and whatnot but I can't figure out a way to loop this to make it cleaner. Essentially what it's doing is it's finding all 8 adjacent tiles around the tile that you press.
Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: +1 Just because i like the question. Off-Topic: Use this for shuffling if you want to improve the shuffling: `fields.OrderBy(p => Guid.NewGuid())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use flood fill.  It is the algorithm that MS uses in theirs.  Change maybe to an array that stores the cell values without using string.

```
enum CellType 
{
   Bomb,
   Flag,
   Hidden,  
   Empty
}

CellType[,] cells = new CellType[10,10];
```

Basically when someone clicks on a cell check to see if it hidden, check to see if the cells around it are hidden.  Each cell around it that is hidden you would add to queue or stack and then back track.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Updated:
Here is a complete example in C#.  These are recursive instead of using some collection for backtracking
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31909/best-algorithm-for-recursive-adjacent-tiles

Comment: Thanks for the tip, in reading I see it only works with a multi dimensional array? Hence, the way I'm populating my grid wouldn't work:
http://pastebin.com/AN1ikXRn
That's how I'm populating it. In order to get it to work, I would need essentially a 9x9 array, as opposed to an 81 element array?
To my knowledge, you can't programatically populate an array because you can't append to them, you can only append to lists. Is there a way to convert my list to a multi-dimensional array.. OR, to programatically create a multi-dimensional array? Thanks.

Comment: I get an error: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'
I believe this is the problem I was having before which is why I resorted to lists. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry I copy pasted the code.  Change <= to < and start the loop at zero.  http://pastebin.com/iCi5SxVM

Comment: @AbdElRaheim Incidentally, kind of off topic, since you told me to change <= to <, would changing i++ to ++i also do the trick? Edit: just tested it, evidently not. For learning purposes can you tell me why changing <= to < fixed it? I don't see why being equal to the highest boundary would make it out of range.